# SerializableException passing an object with an Intent (putExtra)

Tags: java, android, serialization

I am working on a game where I pass my `Engine` object from one activity to another and then to a third activity. The first pass from activity A to B completes without issue, but when I pass it from B to C then I get an error.

The first activity is `NewGameActivity`, it creates my `Engine` object. `Engine` is `Serializable` and so are all of its children as well as its childrens' children etc.
The `NewGameActivity` passes my `Engine` object onto the `GameActivity` using the following code:

```
// method of the NewGameActivity class
public void newGame(View view) {
    final Engine engine = getEngine();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ENGINE, engine);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

All of this works perfectly fine. The `GameActivity` is able to retrieve the `Engine` object and to start working with it.

Now I have decided to pass my engine to a third activity. From within the `GameActivity` I launch the `BudgetActivity` using the following code:

```
// method of the GameActivity class
public final void showBudget() {
    final Engine engine = this.mainView.getEngine();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BudgetActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(GameActivity.ENGINE, engine);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

So I am passing the exact same object as before. (Of course, the members of the engine have changed a bit)

The problem is that I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = test.engine.Engine)
...
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: test.android.MainView
...
```

`MainView` is an implementation of `android.view.View`. It is the main component that is visible on `GameActivity` and it is the class that executes the call to the `showBudget` method above.

I am very confused at this point because:

1. `Engine` and everything related is `Serializable`
2. I was able to pass `Engine` from `NewGameActivity` to `GameActivity` without any issues
3. Why should `MainView` be `Serializable`? The `Engine` class has no reference to any of my android-specific classes at all

Comment: The code looks correct. We're looking at the wrong part of your app. Please send us your full logcat and try your case with a simple class like a string. Does it work with a string?

Comment: Serialization in Java is tricky, please make sure that every Engine sub-class do the right work. Here is an article about serialization http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/serialization-in-java.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. It turns out that not all of my classes were Serializable, as the error suggested. I was too focused on the fact that the Engine layer had no imports to the MainView class (or to any android-specific class for that matter).

What happened was that the Engine had some kind of an EngineListener and MainView class implemented it. So I made the list of listeners transient and now things are working fine.